# How to center Button using grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to center the button widget in a tkinter frame window using `grid()`. I have tried several solutions included `weights` but none of them center the button widget with text "Choose files". Its either left or right sticked. How could I go about doing this?

I don't want to use `pack()`, by the way. I would like to keep using `grid()`.

```
class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("PDF Merger v0.1")
        self.filenamesopen = []
        self.grid(sticky=W + E + N + S)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Choose files", command=self.load_files, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0,sticky=E+W)

        self.button = Button(self, text="Merge", command=self.merge_files, width=10)
        self.button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.labelframe = LabelFrame(self, text="Files to merge:")
        self.labelframe.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.left = Label(self.labelframe, text="")
        self.left.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
    def load_files(self):
        try:
            self.filenamesopen = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir="/", title="Choose files to merge...",
                                                filetypes=(("pdf", "*.pdf"), ("All files", "*.*")))
            filenames = [os.path.split(file)[1] for file in self.filenamesopen]
            self.left.configure(text="\n".join(filenames))
        except:
            showerror("Open Source File", "Failed to read files\n")

    def merge_files(self):
        self.merger = PdfFileMerger()
        try:
            for pdf in self.filenamesopen:
                self.merger.append(open(pdf, 'rb'), import_bookmarks=False)
        except:
            showerror("Merger Error", "Failed to merge files\n")
            return
        self.save_files()
    def save_files(self):
        try:
            self.filenamesave = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir="/", title="Save as...",
                                     filetypes=(("pdf", "*.pdf"), ("All files", "*.*")),
                                                         defaultextension=".pdf")
            with open(self.filenamesave, 'wb') as fout:
                self.merger.write(fout)
        except:
            showerror("Save Source File", "Failed to save file\n")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyFrame().mainloop()
```

Comment: Centered in the window, or just centered with respect to the other widgets? Do you expect everything to stay centered when the window is resized?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley, I want it to be centered in the window (when the window is resized as well). In the end I'd like to center everything but firstly I tried to center one of the Button widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center a widget inside a window or frame with `grid()` you need to set weight to the cell where the widget is. The widget will center automatically whenever the size is changed. See example below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)   # Set weight to row and 
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)      # column where the widget is

container = Frame(root, bg='tan')   # bg color to show extent
container.grid(row=0, column=0)     # Grid cell with weight

# A couple of widgets to illustrate the principle.
b1 = Button(container, text='First', width=10)
b1.grid(pady=10, padx=20)
b2 = Button(container, text='second', width=10)
b2.grid(pady=(0,10), padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

An excellent reference at: [The Tkinter Grid Geometry Manager](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm)

Comment: Thank you @figbeam! I implemented your hints into my code, restructured a bit the code and it works. I am still a newbie in tkinter.